# Create a diagram from cvs: treat a contraction of numbers like a single number

Tags: pgfplots

I’m trying to have a diagram that shows the information produced by this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Jahr, Treffer
1995-2010, 4
2005, 3
2006, 7
2007, 15
2008, 68
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{data.csv}
\end{document}
```

Instead of `\csvautotabular{data.csv}`, I tried this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ]

    \addplot table [x=Jahr, y=Treffer, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but get the error

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '1995-2010' as a
floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '-2010'..
```

Is there a good way around this, like treating the 1995-2010 as a string and pretending it’s just another single year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the idea from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21224/85494), you can insert a third column "Label" in your `.csv` which keeps the label strings, and just have the beginning of the year range as x-values for the plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Jahr, Treffer, Label
1995, 4, 1995-2004
2005, 3, 2005
2006, 7, 2006
2007, 15, 2007
2008, 68, 2008
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{data.csv}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={data.csv}{Label}
    ]

    \addplot table [x=Jahr, y=Treffer, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, the labels are quite long and thus overlapping, so [apply some make-up to your plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27143/85494).

**EDIT**: In particular I like the idea of having horizontal bars:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={data.csv}{Label}
    ]

    \addplot table [y=Jahr, x=Treffer, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, again, cauchy42! Your answer perfectly solved my problem. Concerning the overlapping years, I’ll take a look at the suggested question & answer.